# Add columns in R based on condition

Tags: r

I have a dataframe containing 3 columns. I need to add 2 new columns dependend on whether there is 0/1 or 1/1 in the third column. in case of 0/1 the output is
the same but in case of 1/1 it would be the first column of the output which becomes as same as the second. Appreciate any help.

Example:

```
G   A   0/1  -->   G   A
C   T   0/1  -->   C   T
A   G   1/1  -->   G   G
C   G   1/1  -->   G    G
T   C   1/1  -->   C    C
A   G   1/1  -->   G    G
G   A   0/1  -->   G    A
A   G   1/1  -->   G    G
```

Comment: Why do you need the second new column? It doesn't make a difference for the observations.

Comment: Why the `A G` is converted `1 1` ? According to the earlier description, if there is any difference between the columns, it should be `0 1`

Comment: Don't just post an example. Describe your problem as well. Please read: [ask]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do what you want:

```
df$new1 <- +(df$V1==df$V2)
df$new2 <- 1
```

or (inspired by @arkun's answer):

```
df <- cbind(df, new1 = +(df$V1==df$V2), new2 = 1)
```

this gives the following dataframe:

```
> df
  V1 V2 new1 new2
1  A  A    1    1
2  A  G    0    1
3  T  T    1    1
4  C  C    1    1
5  A  C    0    1
6  A  G    0    1
7  G  G    1    1
```

Used data:

```
df <- read.table(text="A    A 
A    G  
T    T  
C    C  
A    C  
A    G 
G    G", header=FALSE)
```

---

For the new example:

```
df$new1 <- ifelse(df$V3=="0/1", as.character(df$V1), as.character(df$V2))
df$new2 <- df$V2
```

this gives:

```
> df
  V1 V2  V3 new1 new2
1  G  A 0/1    G    A
2  C  T 0/1    C    T
3  A  G 1/1    G    G
4  C  G 1/1    G    G
5  T  C 1/1    C    C
6  A  G 1/1    G    G
7  G  A 0/1    G    A
8  A  G 1/1    G    G
```

Used data:

```
df <- structure(list(V1 = structure(c(3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 1L), .Label = c("A", "C", "G", "T"), class = "factor"), 
                     V2 = structure(c(1L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L), .Label = c("A", "C", "G", "T"), class = "factor"),
                     V3 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("0/1", "1/1"), class = "factor")),
                .Names = c("V1", "V2", "V3"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))
```

Comment: both of the input columns are in one dataframe and the output should be as well in the same as 3rd and 4th column. Is this possible? Thank you very much.

Comment: @sugsiv that's exactly what my answer is showing: for example `df$new1 <- +(df$V1==df$V2)` creates a new (output) column in the existing dataframe

Comment: sorry but this is however a little bit different then before. I have

Comment: sorry but this is however a little bit different then before. can you have a look at the example above

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to convert the logical vector (`df1[,1]==df1[,2]`) to numeric index by adding 1, use that to populate the strings `0 1`, `1 1` and read with `read.table` to create two columns.

```
read.table(text=c('0 1', '1 1')[(df1[,1]==df1[,2])+1L], header=FALSE)
#  V1 V2
#1  1  1
#2  0  1
#3  1  1
#4  1  1
#5  0  1
#6  0  1
#7  1  1
```

Or just use `cbind` as the second column is always 1.

```
cbind(df1[,1]==df1[,2],1)
```

#### Update

For the second example (@Jaap's dataset), we can also use `row/column` indexing to create the 'new1' column, and 'new2' is basically the same as 'V2' (not sure why a duplicate column is needed though).

```
transform(df, new1 = df[2:1][cbind(1:nrow(df),(V3=='0/1')+1L)],
              new2 = df[,2])
#  V1 V2  V3 new1 new2
#1  G  A 0/1    G    A
#2  C  T 0/1    C    T
#3  A  G 1/1    G    G
#4  C  G 1/1    G    G
#5  T  C 1/1    C    C
#6  A  G 1/1    G    G
#7  G  A 0/1    G    A
#8  A  G 1/1    G    G
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Col1 = c("A", "A", "T", "C", "A", "A", "G"), 
Col2 = c("A", 
"G", "T", "C", "C", "G", "G")), .Names = c("Col1", "Col2"), 
row.names = c(NA, -7L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: can you have a look at the new problem? example above

Comment: @sugsiv I didn't understand your new problem, which is kind of different than what you described earlier

Comment: when the third column is 1/1 the output is always the same as the second column. is that better to understand?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `dplyr` and `tidyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
z %>% separate(V3, into = c("col1", "col2"), remove = FALSE) %>%
    mutate_each(funs(ifelse(. == 0, as.character(V1), as.character(V2))), -V1, -V2, -V3)
  V1 V2  V3 col1 col2
1  G  A 0/1    G    A
2  C  T 0/1    C    T
3  A  G 1/1    G    G
4  C  G 1/1    G    G
5  T  C 1/1    C    C
6  A  G 1/1    G    G
7  G  A 0/1    G    A
8  A  G 1/1    G    G
```