# Add columns in R based on condition 3

Tags: r

The issue is to add a new column to a dataframe when a condition is fulfilled. When the first columns are 1  1  then a "hom" and when 0  1 a "het" should be outputted. Appreciate any help.

Example:

```
1  1  -->  hom
1  1  -->  hom
0  1  -->  het 
1  1  -->  hom
0  1  -->  het
```

Comment: Would `0 0` be `hom`  or `het`? And how about `1 0`? Shouldn't that be `het`?

Comment: Did you read the answers on your [earlier question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33125739/add-columns-in-r-based-on-condition)?

Comment: yes, i did. thx for your help. in this there is no 1  0  existent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If these are the only two conditions to check , then checking only first column of dataframe is sufficient

```
df <- data.frame(num1 = c(1,0,1), num2 = c(1,1,1))
ifelse(df$num1 == 1,"hom","het")
# [1] "hom" "het" "hom"
```

Comment: @sugsiv You can accept any one solution which works for you

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
 c('het', 'horn')[as.numeric(factor(do.call(paste, df1)))]
 #[1] "horn" "horn" "het"  "horn" "het"
```

Or if the first column is only changing

```
 c('het', 'horn')[df1[,1]+1L]
 #[1] "horn" "horn" "het"  "horn" "het"
```

#### data

```
 df1 <- data.frame(V1 = c(1, 1, 0, 1, 0), V2= 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
df1[,3] <- ifelse(xor(df1[,1],df1[,2]),"het","hom")
#> df1
#  V1 V2  V3
#1  1  1 hom
#2  1  1 hom
#3  0  1 het
#4  1  1 hom
#5  0  1 het
```

Note that, in contrast to the answer by @RonakShah , this will return `het` for the combination `1 0`. I assume that this is plausible, but it would be helpful if you could clarify whether the expected output depends solely on column 1 or on the values in the two columns, irrespective of their order. Moreover, it is not clear what the expected output would be for the combination `0 0`. This code would return `hom` for `0 0`.

Comment: Based on the previous questions posted by the OP, it seems there are only two possible outcomes.

Comment: @akrun I understand this - there will be only "hom" or "het", but I would like to know whether `0 0` is `hom` or `het`. It looks like a "homogeneous" combination to me, but only the OP can clarify this.

Comment: @akrun I may have misunderstood you. Do you mean that the only possible combinations are `0 1` and `1 1`? Then things become easy since one can discard the second column, as suggested by Ronak Shah.

Comment: Yes, that is my understanding from looking at his previous questions.

Comment: Ok thank you. We'll see if the OP provides more information.

Comment: 0  0 is hom but not existent in my example but is the true possible

Comment: thx for your suggestions